# Make visual studio do spaces before and after '='

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Always when I finish a statement I write `;` and it formats the statement, like `1+2+3` to `1 + 2 + 3`. But it doesn't do it to `x=y` to `x = y`. Why? How to make it to do that?

I read everything in `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Formatting -> Spacing` and didn't saw anything that is even related to `=`.

Comment: It does it for me(2010). Btw, what VS version are you using at all?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Visual Studio 2013, I think because of that it annoyed me that they changed it(?).

Comment: It works that way for me on 2013, but I have Resharper which gives you a lot of control over formatting.

Comment: @juharr That's can be an answer, I will check this plugin again.

Comment: It works that way for me on VS2013 Premium and I don't have ReSharper.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Actually pretty weird I think. I could enable this only with ReSharper.

Comment: Do you have `Insert space before and after binary operators` selected?  The only time I have weird problems with formatting is when I have a syntax error in the code above.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Of course I have. +-*/ are all having before and after binary operations but =. (I explicitly said it in the question) About the syntax error, I don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). It provides much more features in code editing. also you can press Ctrl + KD to make formatting.